# Android update widget on hardware button press

Tags: android, android-widget

Is it possible to update an android widget when **hardware** button is pressed (side volume button, for instance)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible as you cannot listen to events on the volume, power, home, back and menu buttons if your app is not in the foreground.

On some device you may listen to the camera button, but that is present on very few devices.